# Laravel - GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/emer911/public/css/app.css [HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found 291ms]

Tags: html, css, laravel

I'm using a blade template to include the css code with

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

and I'm compiling the code with

```
npm run watch // also tried straigh up npm run dev
```

I'm using the sass in /resources/sass/app.scss, and I can see it compile to /public/css/app.css but still the page can't find the file.

Also, if it's any help the program also can't find the js file

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/emer911/public/js/app.js
[HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found 154ms]
```

I'm just learning to use laravel, so I don't know if I did anything wrong, but I don't think so... Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using `php artisan serve` to serve your files? Or Apache/nginx? (`public/` should not appear in the url and should be the "DocumentRoot" for your server/vhost)

Comment: @brombeer I'm using `php artisan serve` , should I change the way I include the css to fix the route?

Comment: Ohhkay, are you running it from inside your project folder?

Comment: @brombeer Yeah, should I do it from outside? Like, from the laravel folder?

Comment: share your websocket.js pls

Comment: @HamidShariati the one in /transport or the one in /transport/browser?

Comment: excuse me webpack.js

Comment: @HamidShariati This is all that's inside my webpack.js

`const mix = require('laravel-mix');


mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');`

Comment: what's the result of npm run watch?

Comment: @HamidShariati  DONE  Compiled successfully in 138ms                                                                                                                                                                                                  7:21:18

       Asset       Size   Chunks             Chunk Names
/css/app.css  171 bytes  /js/app  [emitted]  /js/app
 + 1 hidden asset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use mix instead of asset:

```
<link href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Can't upvote 'cuz I just created the account a few days back, but thank you so much for your help!!